# Configuring Apache session correctly

Tags: apache-2.2

I am trying to configure Apache to timeout sessions correctly. I have had a look through some results in Google but didn't quite understand how to set this.

Basically I would the users session to timeout after 15 mins of inactivity and also if the  users browser is completely closed. Please can some one advise which settings I would need to change to achieve this? I would prefer to configure this at a global level rather than the vhost.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP has no concept of "sessions" - if you provide a session cookie after some scripted (non-apache) login procedure, then that is where this all happens.

You could configure the application to set the cookie to expire after 15 minutes; for this to work interactively you'd need to periodically re-check the cookie status from the application (e.g. using a global meta refresh, or AJAX).